# Unintentionally assisting someone's suicide

Tags: suicide

Let's say I drop my gun on the street (accidentally or not). A man walks by, picks up my gun, and shoots himself in the head.

Should I be convicted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *legal* question is whether you can be convicted of a crime under the laws of some jurisdiction on earth. I'll start by assuming that you are in a jurisdiction where you can legally possess firearms and carry them in public. Since you added "and commits suicide", I assume you're not asking if it is a crime to drop a firearm, the question is just criminal culpability for this consequence. Now we will zoom into the laws of a specific jurisdiction, Washington state. [RCW 9A.36.060](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.36.060) says

> A person is guilty of promoting a suicide attempt when he or she
> knowingly causes or aids another person to attempt suicide.

The question then is whether your act "knowingly causes or aids" an attempted suicide. You turn to [the jury instructions](https://govt.westlaw.com/wcrji/Document/Ief9e62d9e10d11daade1ae871d9b2cbe?transitionType=Default&bhcp=1&contextData=(sc.Default)&ignorebhwarn=IgnoreWarns) to see what that means:

> A person knows or acts knowingly or with knowledge with respect to a
> [fact] [circumstance] [or] [result] when he or she is aware of that
> [fact] [circumstance] [or] [result]. [It is not necessary that the
> person know that the [fact] [circumstance] [or] [result] is defined by
> law as being unlawful or an element of a crime.] If a person has
> information that would lead a reasonable person in the same situation
> to believe that a fact exists, the jury is permitted but not required
> to find that he or she acted with knowledge of that fact. [When acting
> knowingly [as to a particular fact] is required to establish an
> element of a crime, the element is also established if a person acts
> intentionally [as to that fact].]

The outcome depends on specific circumstances. For example, "accidentally and unknowingly drop and leave" will not sustain a conviction. "Intentionally drop and leave" could, but you would also have to other information connecting the suicide to the availability of a weapon. If you intentionally drop and leave a firearm at a shooting range, a reasonable person would not think "OMG someone might see this weapon and kill themselves with it! Hahaha!". You can spin a yarn where you know that Smith is suicidal and will kill himself if he has a weapon, so that dropping the gun off constitutes "knowingly aiding".